# Loop to compare elements from 2 columns

Tags: jquery, loops, compare

I have two columns, some of which contain elements with the class "parentandsub".

I want to loop through each parentandsub element in Column A, and check to see if it's in Column B. If it's not, then I want to highlight that element in Column A.

Here is my code, but it's not working:

```
$(".column2 .parentandsub").each(function(){

    if ($(".column1 .parentandsub:contains('" + $(this).html() + "')").length == 0) {
     $(this).wrap('<span class="parentandsubhilite" />');
    }

});
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example of what you currently have? There may be a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".column2 .parentandsub").each(function(index){
    if ($(".column1 .parentandsub:nth-child("+(index+1)+"):contains("+$(this).html()+")").length== 0) {
       $(this).wrap('<span class="parentandsubhilite" />');
    }
});
```